# How to tell the screen reader to read the value of the attribute?

Tags: css, accessibility, screen-readers

I am hoping someone could enlighten me on exactly what is the fix to pseudo classes and `content` negatively impacting screen readers.

For example, if I have this piece of code in my SASS file:

```
[bag-total]:before{
        content: attr(bag-total);
      }
```

My intent here is for the screen reader to read the value of the attribute or the total amount in the users' cart that he is about to purchase.

The problem right now is the screen reader is not reading the number of items in total inside the shopping cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the CSS and user-agent specifications support what you're trying to do here, but inconsistent browser support may ultimately prevent it from working well.

I tested your method using NVDA on Windows with several browsers, and Internet Explorer was the only one that had difficulty. IE still has a fairly sizeable user-base, so it's probably worth supporting if you can.

Unfortunately, I can't see a good solution to your problem unless you want to use JavaScript or a server-side scripting language. Both of these methods add the content to the DOM, whereby CSS doesn't.

This page has some good information on the accessibility of pseudo-elements that seemed to confirm what I was seeing in my own testing.
https://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/

Comment: While Léonie has great blogs on accessibility subjects, just be careful that you confirm the results in any blog that's 3 years old because both browsers and assistive technology change a great deal in that time.

Comment: That being said, I hear the same problem as @Josh in IE.  It happens with both NVDA and JAWS in IE but works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @Josh, I have used ChromeVox screen reader and sure enough, screen reader recognized the shopping cart known as "my bag", but did not say how many items were in it, but you did not have difficulty in Chrome?

Comment: @Ale, Yes - In my tests, Chrome correctly announced the accessible name including the :before and :after pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are used in the "[accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name)" computation as defined here - https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2.  Specifically, step 2.F.ii

The process looks complex but if you think of simple cases, such as a button, the accessible name is essentially the text label of the button.  However, a button that displays "read more" might make sense for a sighted user because they can see the context around the button, but for a visually impaired user that is using screen reading software, "read more" might not be sufficient.  It's possible to add more context to the button label using [ARIA attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes).  The additional context is not visually displayed but is used in the "accessible name" computation, which is why that process looks complex.

The same is true if your button just displays an icon. There is no visible text but you need some way to describe the button's icon so that the "accessible name" will make sense.

If you use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to add more context to your element, that additional context needs to be included in the "accessible name" computation.

Now, all that being said, I'm not sure what kind of "fix" you're looking for.  You didn't really state what the problem is you're trying to fix.

Comment: I just added the problem I am trying to fix.

Comment: As mentioned by @Josh, this appears to be an IE bug.  The spec (as mentioned above) is very clear that `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are supposed to be honored and included in the accessible name computation.  As far as how to fix the IE problem, I'm not sure.  You have to weigh the pros/cons of trying to work around a browser bug vs writing your code according to spec.